How to use function return values within the decorator function
I'm stumped on how to solve this. I'm testing sending GET requests using the Python requests module. The idea is that if I get back a response.status_code of greater than 500, I should retry the request.
So far, I've implemented the solution to retry the request regardless of the status code, and it works perfectly fine. However, I'm struggling to pass in the status_code of the initial call in the main() function into the retry_requests decorator function.
For example, if the status_code was 404, I want the retry_requests decorator to acknowledge that and NOT RUN the decorator at all. If the status_code was 5xx, I want the retry_requests decorator to acknowledge that run the retry_requests.
I have the following working code below.
import requests, time

def retry_requests(func, retries=3):
    def retry_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        attempts = 0
        while attempts < retries:
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                print(f"Error as {e}.") 
                attempts +=1
                time.sleep(3)
    return retry_wrapper

@retry_requests
def get_request():
    response = requests.get("https://this-url-does-not-exist-sorry-jwsgudkaad")
    status_code = response.status_code
    return status_code

def main():
    status_code = get_request()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I want to pass the status_code into the decorator so I can reference it in the while-loop. So it would be: `
while (attempts < retries) and (status_code > 5):

I've got a workaround whereby I could set a ENV or global variable with the status code or uses the requests retry logic. However, I was wondering if it was actually possible to do with my original idea within the decorator function itself. I guess this is more so me figuring out how I was implementing it wrong.
When I define it within the function I get TypeError: retry_requests() missing 1 required positional argument: 'status_code'
I don't want to run the function again prior to me returning it. I just want to access the returned outputs of the initial call in the decorator.

Not sure I understand. You want retry_requests to have a status_code parameter, and then be called with status_code argument being whatever returns get_requests? How could this be possible? retry_requests is the one calling get_requests, right (well, not really calling it. But returning the function that calls it)? I am probably missing the point. But it would help if you clarify that point. Where exactly that status_code argument should come from?

So yes, I want retry_requests to have the status_code parameter. This will only be used in the While loop as another condition status_code > 500. The status_code argument value comes from the returned values from get_requests(). When the get_requests() is first called, I want the status_code from the first all to be passed into the retry_requests decorator so I can use it as a condition for the While Loop.
I tried specifying it in the decorator parameters but I just got a TypeError as mentioned above.

I'm still confused from the description. But if it is not a chicken-egg problem, the status_code is here: return func(*args, **kwargs) the function returns a tuple: (json_response, status_code). Just do not return immediately. Instead save the result of the call, inspect it and return  the result if everything is OK.

Have you considered using the traditional retry mechanism available in requests? Also, calling response.json() unconditionally is not a good pattern

@VPfB I just want to use the returned status_code in the first function call in main() in the decorator as an argument. I have a workaround which does save the result of the call and does like you said - which works totally fine. I was wondering if it is possible to do with my original thought. I don't want to make the function call again prior to the While Loop, but just use the returned results from initial call in main()

@SIGHUP Thanks for the comment. Yes, this is doable. I can use the specify the retry strategy and mount it into my Request Sessions. I guess this question was more so for me to figure out where I was going wrong with the decorator and how I was implementing it incorrectly.

Why do you want to use the returned status code as an argument? It sounds like that's where the confusion and roadblocks are coming from. The decorator already has easy access to anything the wrapped function returns, but not as an argument to the decorator.

@user2357112 Thanks for the comment. I initially wanted to use the status_code so that the retry_requests would on run when status codes were greater than 500. I'm just not sure how I can access that variable from within my decorator. I have a solution that solves this, but was curious if it was possible or how to access the status_code from within the decorator.

Like VPfB said, the status code is the thing you're returning in return func(*args, **kwargs). So don't immediately return it - save the value and inspect it first. status_code = func(*args, **kwargs).

(At the time VPfB left their comment, that value was a tuple with the status code embedded in it, but now it's just the status code directly, so the job is even easier. You might need to adjust things again to actually get any data from the request, though.)

@user2357112 My thought process was that I don't want to call the function again, save the value prior to me returning it as I would have to make another request call in spite of the error code. For example, if the status_code was 404, I want the retry_requests decorator to acknowledge that and not run the decorator at all. I guess another reroute my question to set a conditional for 'retry_request' decorator.

You need to modify the decorator to capture the return value of the decorated function and use it to decide whether to retry the request based on the HTTP status code.

"For example, if the status_code was 404, I want the retry_requests decorator to acknowledge that and not run the decorator at all." - what? But you can't even get far enough to have a status code without running the decorator.

@user2357112 and VPfb . Thanks, I completely understand now. I initially thought get_requests() was called initially, then the decorator would run with function as the argument. This is just my misunderstanding of how decorators work. But your comments completely resolves my issue and your solution completely makes sense. So technically there wasn't anything wrong with my implementation, I just got to move some things around, Thanks for the help! It's much appreciated and helps me learn. Will post the solution when updated.

This is resolved from comments. Thanks @VPfB and @user2357112. This issue was due to a misunderstanding of how decorators work in Python. The get_requests() is first called inside of the decorator as opposed to as outside of the decorate as I initially thought. The correct implementation should call status_code = func(*args, **kwargs), inspect the status_code and return the status_code.
Alternatively,@SIGHUP offered the requests module retry logic. This completely doable and works as an alternative to setting up best methods to retry requests.
Marked the answer as Community Wiki
